# how to find an overall min-cut separating some node pairs

Tags: graph

As we know, now there is efficient algorithms to find the overall min-cut in a directed graph, e.g. Hao and Orlin (1994).

Now my problem is to find an overall min-cut just separating some given node pairs, not all the node pairs. For example, I have an 8-node digraph with capacities on each arc and want to find the min-cut separating 8 and 1, 6 and 3, 7 and 1.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve the *minimum multicut problem*, which is NP-Hard but also extensively studied in literature. 
E.g. http://scholar.google.be/scholar?q=minimum+multicut+directed+graph&btnG=&lr=

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. As I mentioned, now there are efficient algorithms for finding overall min cut separating all node pairs. Here, I want a good algorithm to find overall min cut just separating some node pairs.

Comment: I think I did understand your answer :). You want to *find overall min cut just separating some node pairs.* And this is called a *multi*cut. This problem is an open research question, and as far as I know, there is no "good" algorithm because the problem is so hard. Most algorithms are stochastic or tackle only a certain subclass of graphs, eg http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3999
So you should look which algorithm best suits your needs..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I did not explain my question clearly. My problem is different from the minimum multicut problem, which is to find a minimum weight set of edges whose removal separates each pair of given source and sink. But my problem is to determine the minimum from all cuts separating each node pair.For example, I have a 4-node digraph and node pairs {1,4},{2,4} and {1,3}. Then I want to find the minimum one among min-cut separating 1 and 4,  min-cut separating 2 and 4, and min-cut separating 1 and 3.

Comment: In that case, the easiest solution is to calculate the min-cut for each pair, and pick the cheapest one. I do not think much speed-up can be expected by solving the problem in one combined step.

Comment: Yes, this is a difficutly job. I am still trying to modify the algorithm implementation of Hao and Orlin (1994) for my purpose. The current difficutly is how to exclude those cuts separating some not-considered node pairs.

Comment: @shaon If you say "I think I did not explain my question clearly", then it would be good if you could update your question itself, without assuming everyone will read all the comments. It's a very interesting problem anyway.